# How do I convert the vector of hair curve to father mesh's vertex_color by python?

Tags: python, bezier-curves, hair, vertex-colors

[image]

***How to turn hair's vector(XYZ) to monkey's vertex color(RGB)***

**This is the maya python,I want to convert this code to Blender,What should I write？**

````
import maya.cmds as mc
import pymel.core as pm
import maya.OpenMaya as om


def convert_vertex_color():
    selected = mc.ls(sl=1)
    obj_name = selected[0]
    name = mc.duplicate(selected[0], rr=1)
    selected[0] = name[0]
    print selected
    mc.select(selected)
    selected_list = mc.ls(sl=1)

    if len(selected_list) < 2 or len(selected_list) > 2:
        mc.warning('Please select the number of objects correctly')
        return
    obj = pm.PyNode(selected_list[0]).__apimdagpath__()
    mfn_mesh = om.MFnMesh(obj)
    vertex_iter = om.MItMeshVertex(obj)
    group_name = selected_list[2]
    color_list = om.MColorArray()
    index_list = om.MIntArray()
    for curve in mc.listRelatives(group_name, c=1, f=1):

        if mc.objectType(mc.listRelatives(curve, c=1, s=1)) != 'nurbsCurve':
            continue

        point1 = mc.pointPosition(curve + '.cv[0]', w=1)
        point2 = mc.pointPosition(curve + '.cv[2]', w=1)
        vector = om.MVector(om.MVector(point2[0] - point1[0], point2[2] - point1[2], point2[2] - point1[2]))
        vector.normalize()
        while not vertex_iter.isDone():

            pos = vertex_iter.position(om.MSpace.kWorld)

            if abs(pos[0] - point1[0]) <= 0.1 and abs(pos[2] - point1[2]) <= 0.1 and abs(pos[2] - point1[2]) <= 0.1:

                color_list.append(om.MColor((vector[0]+1)/2, (vector[2]+1)/2, (vector[2]+1)/2))
                index_list.append(vertex_iter.index())

            vertex_iter.next()
        vertex_iter.reset()
    mfn_mesh.setVertexColors(color_list, index_list, None, om.MFnMesh.kRGB)

    mc.transferAttributes(selected_list[0], obj_name, pos=0, nml=0, uvs=0, col=2, spa=0, sm=3, flipUVs=0, clb=0)
    mc.setAttr(selected_list[0] + '.visibility', 0)
    mc.warning('Finished')


convert_vertex_color()```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXdwF.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dClT1.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

This code can turn Vertex Position into Vertex Colors,that all I Know.I'm a fresh.

````
import bpy
from mathutils import Color, Vector

my_object = bpy.context.active_object.data
vert_list = my_object.vertices
color_map_collection = my_object.vertex_colors

if len(color_map_collection) == 0:
    color_map_collection.new()

color_map = color_map_collection['Col']


i = 0
for poly in my_object.polygons:
    for idx in poly.loop_indices:
        loop = my_object.loops[idx]
        v = loop.vertex_index
        x = (vert_list[v].co.x + 1) / 2
        y = (vert_list[v].co.y + 1) / 2
        z = (vert_list[v].co.z + 1) / 2
        t = 0
        final = (x,y,z,t)
        color_map.data[i].color = final
        i += 1


# set to vertex paint mode to see the result
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')```
````